# JSON:API resources error: "This resource attempted to serve data that contains unsupported resource types."

Tags: 8

I'm trying to make a custom JSON:API resource for flaggings using the [JSON:API Resources](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources) module.

Right now, I simply want to return all the flaggings of a given bundle with an EntityQuery.  (Later, I will customize the EntityQuery, which is why I am need to go beyond what JSON:API provides by default.)

My code is [based on the module's example code.](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/jsonapi_resources/-/blob/8.x-1.x/tests/modules/jsonapi_resources_test/src/Resource/AuthorArticles.php)

**MYMODULE/src/Resource/MyQueue.php**

```
/**
 * Processes a request for a collection containing a user's article nodes.
 *
 * @internal
 */
class MyQueue extends EntityQueryResourceBase {

  /**
   * Process the resource request.
   *
   * Code example:
   * https://git.drupalcode.org/project/jsonapi_resources/tree/8.x-1.x/tests/modules/jsonapi_resources_test/src/Resource.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   *   The request.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\jsonapi\ResourceResponse
   *   The response.
   *
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException
   * @throws \Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException
   */
  public function process(Request $request): ResourceResponse {

    $cacheability = new CacheableMetadata();

    $entity_type_id = 'flagging';
    $entity_type_bundle = 'MY_FLAGGING_TYPE';
    $entity_type = $this->entityTypeManager->getDefinition($entity_type_id);
    $entity_query = $this->getEntityQuery($entity_type_id)
      ->condition($entity_type->getKey('bundle'), $entity_type_bundle);

    $paginator = $this->getPaginatorForRequest($request);
    $paginator->applyToQuery($entity_query, $cacheability);

    $data = $this->loadResourceObjectDataFromEntityQuery($entity_query, $cacheability);

    $pagination_links = $paginator->getPaginationLinks($entity_query, $cacheability, TRUE);

    $response = $this->createJsonapiResponse($data, $request, 200, [], $pagination_links);
    $response->addCacheableDependency($cacheability);

    return $response;
  }

}
```

With this code, I'm getting the following error:

> LogicException: This resource attempted to serve data that contains
> unsupported resource types.

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, or what it means.

- If I set `$entity_type_id` to `node` and `$entity_type_bundle` to `page`, everything works as expected.
- If I set the `$entity_type_id` to 'custom_content_type`, one of the content types I configured in the admin UI, it doesn't work; I get the same error.
- I tried to set `$entity_type_bundle` to all three flagging bundles on my site; none of them work.
- The `$entity_query` is correct for the flaggings.  I can do `$entity_query->count->execute()` and I get the correct count.
- I am logged in as an administrator with all permissions.
- I can access the jsonapi in my browser as an admin at `/jsonapi/flagging/MY_FLAGGING_TYPE` and I see the flaggings as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is the result of not setting the `_jsonapi_resource` correctly in the routing file:

**MYMODULE.routing.yml**

```
# Defines a route where a user's flaggings can be found.
MYMODULE.user_flaggings:
  # %jsonapi% is a placeholder for the JSON:API base path, which can be
  # configured in a site's services.yml file.
  path: '/%jsonapi%/MYMODULE/queue'
  defaults:
    # Every JSON:API resource route must declare a _jsonapi_resource. The
    # value can either be a class or a service ID. Unlike the _controller
    # route default, it is not possible to declare a method name to be called.
    _jsonapi_resource: Drupal\MYMODULE\Resource\MyQueue
    _jsonapi_resource_types: ['node--page', 'flagging--MY_FLAGGING_TYPE']
```